# Automapper, mapping single destination property as a concatenation of multiple source property

Tags: automapper, automapper-3

I have a situation where I need to map a single property as a combination of multiple source properties based on some conditions.

Destination :

```cs
public class Email
{
    public Email() {
        EmailRecipient = new List<EmailRecipient>();
    }
    public string Subject{get; set;}
    public string Body {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<EmailRecipient> EmailRecipient { get; set; } 
}

public class EmailRecipient
{
    public int EmaiId { get; set; }
    public string RecipientEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int RecipientEmailTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Email Email { get; set; }
}
```

Source:

```cs
public class EmailViewModel
{
    public List<EmailRecipientViewModel> To { get; set; }
    public List<EmailRecipientViewModel> Cc { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class EmailRecipientViewModel
{
    public string RecipientEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I want `Mapper.Map<EmailViewModel,Email>()`

Here I would like to map my `Email.EmailRecipient` as a combination of `EmailViewModel.To` and `EmailViewModel.Cc`.
However the condition is, `Email.EmailRecipient.RecipientEmailTypeId` will be 1 for **To** and 2 for **Cc**

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way to achieve this is to create a map that uses a specific method for this conversion. The map creation would be:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<EmailViewModel, Email>()
    .ForMember(e => e.EmailRecipient, opt => opt.MapFrom(v => JoinRecipients(v)));
```

Where the `JoinRecipients` method would perform the conversion itself. A simple implementation could be something like:

```cs
private ICollection<EmailRecipient> JoinRecipients(EmailViewModel viewModel) {
    List<EmailRecipient> result = new List<EmailRecipient>();
    foreach (var toRecipient in viewModel.To) {
        result.Add(new EmailRecipient {
            RecipientEmailTypeId = 1, 
            RecipientEmailAddress = toRecipient.RecipientEmailAddress
        });
    }

    foreach (var ccRecipient in viewModel.Cc) {
        result.Add(new EmailRecipient {
            RecipientEmailTypeId = 2,
            RecipientEmailAddress = ccRecipient.RecipientEmailAddress
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm a huge opponent of converters, mostly because for other people in your project, things will just happen 'like magic' after the mapping call.

An easier way of handling this would be to implement the property as a method that converts other properties on the viewmodel to the required formatting. Example:

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
    public ICollection<EmailRecipient> EmailRecipient { 
        get {
             return To.Union(Cc);
        } 
    }
    public List<EmailRecipientViewModel> To { get; set; }
    public List<EmailRecipientViewModel> Cc { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Now automapper automatically maps from EmailRecipient property to EmailRecipient property, and if someone is trying to figure out how it happens, they just need to look on the viewmodel.

Editing this some years later: Just as a warning, doing things this way means that every time you call EmailRecipient, you incur the o(n) task of unioning the `To` and `Cc` fields. This is fine if you're only dealing with one email, but if you're reusing the viewmodel and someone sticks it in a loop with say, every other email in the system, it might be a huge performance issue. In that case I'd go with the accepted answer so that you dodge this potential performance pitfall.