# Use Automapper to combine two fields in destination

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called EmployeeDto which has property FirstName and LastName,

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

While using automapper to convert to employee I want to combine FirstName and LastName and add that to Name field

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper, mapping single destination property as a concatenation of multiple source property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220501/automapper-mapping-single-destination-property-as-a-concatenation-of-multiple-s)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CreateMap to map FirstName and Lastname to Name

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
                        .ForMember(d => d.Name, d => d.MapFrom(x => string.Format("{0}{1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Define an explicit mapping for `Name`:

```
CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Name,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.FirstName} {src.LastName}"));
```

In the case that `FirstName` or `LastName` could be null, it would be tidier to trim the interpolation result:

```
$"{src.FirstName} {src.LastName}".Trim()
```